# Kotlin : Function invocation 'buffer()' expected

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, properties

I write an OkHttp Log Interceptor using `responseBody.source().buffer`.
It works fine when I run the app with Android Studio, but it fails to compile when I try to build an APK.

```
e: F:\source\ZZCloud\lib.frame\src\main\java\com\fine\mps\net\FineHttpLogger.kt: (117, 37): Function invocation 'buffer()' expected
```

The buffer code:

```kotlin
interface BufferedSource : Source, ReadableByteChannel {
  /** Returns this source's internal buffer. */
  @Deprecated(
    message = "moved to val: use getBuffer() instead",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith(expression = "buffer"),
    level = DeprecationLevel.WARNING)
  fun buffer(): Buffer

 /** This source's internal buffer. */
  val buffer: Buffer
}
```

My code at FineHttpLogger.kt: (117, 37):

```kotlin
val source = responseBody.source()
var buffer = source.buffer
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access property `val buffer`, but compiler is treating `buffer` as a function, because there `fun buffer()` with the same name as of the property. Can you show us the code at `FineHttpLogger.kt: (117, 37)`?

Comment: My code at FineHttpLogger.kt(117,37) is `var buffer = source.buffer` @fdermishin

Comment: Did you try to change it to `var buffer = source.buffer()`?

Comment: If I change source.buffer to source.buffer() it compile success. But source.buffer works fine when I run app directly in AndroidStudio，it just throws exception when I try to build an APK with gradle like assembleRelease。@fdermishin